# how to embed an application inside panel after removing its title bar

Tags: c#

1. I can place application inside any panel using SetParent() method of user32.dll
2. I can remove title bar also using SetWindowLong() and GetWindowLong() user32.dll

My question is... how to merge these two concepts in one application.

Comment: It sounds as if you have figured everything out.  If you need help with the actual code, then post the code that you need help with.

Comment: [Just make sure you know what you're doing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you are really asking but anyway I will try to answer what I think you're asking:

1. Consider you have an application X with ID Y.
2. Put your app inside it using the SetParent call over X.
3. The call SetWindowLong over X.